# Map reduce merge two files without identical key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have two files in HDFS.  The first file contains a record that contains the start time and end time of an employee's day.  He checks into the system at 5am and leaves @ 2pm, and the system records the start time, end time, and duration.

File two contains records which represent the exact time that a customer called our office.

How would I join within HDFS, using pig, m/r, etc., these two files, giving me a result set that represents each of the customers, with all of the employees that were available at the time that they called?

Answer (score 0):

When you say time, what precision are we talking about, minutes, seconds??  One thing could be read employee file and assuming we are talking about minute level precision, keep outputting (time,empID) for every minute till end for each entry in file 1. For file 2, just emit out (time,customer Id). Now reducer will do the needful

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it may be intolerably expensive for large data sets because of the `CROSS`.

```
EmpInOut = LOAD 'empdata' using PigStorage(',') as (empID:int, logInTime:int, logOutTime:int);
CustCalls = LOAD 'custcalls' using PigStorage(',') as (custID:int, callTime:int);
BigMess = CROSS CustCalls, EmpInOut;
EmpsAvail = FILTER BigMess BY logInTime <= callTime AND logOutTime >= callTime;
Answer = GROUP EmpsAvail BY (custID, callTime);
DUMP Answer;
```

I tested using these data files:

file 'empdata':

```
0,0600,1200
1,0700,1400
2,0800,1600
3,0900,1200
4,1000,1900
5,1100,1900
6,1200,2000
```

file 'custcalls':

```
101,0500
102,0630
103,0730
104,0830
105,0930
106,1210
107,1930
```